# Using functions from a jar files n Visual C++ console application

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio-2012, java-native-interface

I an developing a Visual C++ 32-bit application in Visual Studio 2012. 
One module in my application is developed in JAVA and is available as a jar library only. I need to call functions from the jar file in my Visual C++ Console application. These functions are implemented in JAVA. My Visual C++ application will call these functions. These functions will return some value (message) back to the Visual C++ application.

Most of the links/tutorials talk using JNI for accessing C/C++ code in a JAVA Application. How can I access functions/methods from the jar file to my Visual C++ console application?
any help/idea is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

JNI is my answer too. Using JNI you can create a Java Virtual machine in your c++ program and invoke methods on Java classes.

Please check the following link for a small sample. I hope you can build upon this to meet your requirement.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp9502

Comment: Thanks Karthik, The link was helpful. I was reading at some forums that value can't be returned from JAVA methods called from C++. Is there a way to get return values from JAVA methods in my C++ module?

Comment: @Tariq You can call Java methods which return values. There are JNI APIs like CallObjectMethod(), CallLongMethod() etc. Please have a look at JNI.h file(in my machine JNI.h is available at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\include\jni.h) for the different possible Java method invocations